# Getting an Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, function, mysqli, passwords

I have creating a simple login authentication using mysql database and php, I have got an error " **Fatal error:**  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in".

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','secure_login')

if (isset($_POST['user'],$_POST['pass'])){
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
     if (login($username,$password,$mysqli == true)){
         //login sucess
         header('Location: ../stu_pages/welcome.html');
     }else{
         //login failed
         header('Location: ../index.html');
     }
}


function login($username,$password,$mysqli){
   if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `username`, `password` FROM `member` WHERE `username` = ?")){
       $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows === 0){
            $stmt->bind_result($user_id,$user_name,$db_password);
            $stmt->fetch();
             if ($password == $db_password){
                  return true;
             }else{
                  return false;
             }
        }else{
           echo 'no record found';
        }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't store plain text passwords, you **will** get hacked. You should be using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: What's the use of `javascript` tags here?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (login($username,$password,$mysqli == true))
```

replace it with

```
if (login($username,$password,$mysqli) == true)
```